Spotify API not working in vercel deployed env
I integrated with a library now-playing which allows me to see the track I'm currently playing on spotify or the track I last played
// pages/api/now-playing.ts (API route)

import { NowPlaying, Providers } from '@bolajiolajide/now-playing';

export async function GET() {
  const np = new NowPlaying(Providers.SPOTIFY, {
    useCache: false,
    cacheDuration: 30000,
    streamerArgs: {
      clientId: process.env.WSPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID || 'FOO',
      clientSecret: process.env.WSPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET || 'BAR',
      refreshToken: process.env.WSPOTIFY_REFRESH_TOKEN || 'BAZ',
    },
  });

  try {
    const data = await np.fetchCurrentlyPlayingOrLastPlayed();
    return Response.json({ data });
  } catch (error) {
    return Response.json({ error});
  }
}


This works as expected locally. When I play a music, I can see what I'm currently listening to. When I am not playing one, I can see what was last played.
However on deployment to vercel, the track is stuck at what it was when I deploy. Changing the track does not reflect on the deployed link
credentials are exactly the same but the api returns a 304
